# C# How to return named tuple List<(int row, string message)>

Tags: c#, tuples

I am trying to return a named tuple from the function and getting an error. here is a sample code.

```
public List<(int row, string message)> IsAnyTagNull()
{
    List<Tuple<int, string>> rows = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

    for (int row = rowindex; row < (range.RowCount + (rowindex - 1)); row++)
    {
        rows.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(row, "Cell Tag is null of row " + row));
    }
    return  rows
}
```

Above code return error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<int, string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(int row, string message)>'

Comment: You should define your list like :`rows = new List<(int row, string message)>();`

Comment: Replace `Tuple<int, string>` with `(int, string)`

Comment: To elaborate, the former is a [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2) while the latter is a [`ValueTuple<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple).

Comment: Just like `Timer`, .NET defines **multiple** versions of what constitutes a tuple. **Value tuples** such as `(double, int) t1 = (4.5, 3);` (see [`ValueTuple<T1,T2> Struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=net-6.0)) and what I call **"Tuple objects"** such as `new Tuple<string, Nullable<int>>("Jack", 78)` (see [`System.Tuple<T1,T2> Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=net-6.0)).   Just to keep you on your toes, they both exist in the `System` namespace.   At least the multiple `Timer`s have their own namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `List<Tuple<int, string>>` is different from `List<(int row, string message)>`

You can try to create a collection which is `List<(int row, string message)>` type instead of `List<Tuple<int, string>>`

```
public List<(int row, string message)> IsAnyTagNull()
{
    List<(int row, string message)> rows = new List<(int row, string message)>();
    rows.Add((1, "Cell Tag is null of row "));

    return rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define your list like this: `var rows = new List<(int row, string message)>();`

Type `Tuple<int, string>` is interpreted as `(int Item1, string Item2)`